# Tailwindcss auto grid

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to display numbers in grid which should auto adjust (rows and columns) based on screen size (Mobile, Tablet, PC)

May I know which classes to apply ? Since I have no idea which one to use to make it responsive grid.

I tried many classes none worked.

Please find the tailwind code here, https://play.tailwindcss.com/zPTf9qz6vm

```
<div class="grid grid-flow-col  gap-2">
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear on what you are going for. One option you have is to define the number of columns based on breakpoints using `md:grid-cols-3 sm:grid-cols-1`

https://play.tailwindcss.com/lYc9LnURAL

Comment: I don't want to define anything as grid-cols-3. I need a way such that it should adjust based on screen size. I mean it should calculate the number of columns it can fit in the screen and then render the grid.

Comment: I am not sure the best way to do that with Grid. Having rows that fully fill up before wrapping to a new line is the default behavior of `flex` with `flex-wrap`. This example is closer to what you described:  https://play.tailwindcss.com/swQLQil8TB

Comment: Yes, you nailed it. This is what I want. Thank you Kenny.

Answer (score 0):

I create a sample [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/YoyKIxCprL) for your reference. You should include the class `container` and `mx-auto` at the top-level element. Then, you should use `grid-cols-x` to adjust the column that u want.

```html
<div class="container mx-auto">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4">
    <div class="flex justify-center rounded-xl border-2 border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 p-6 text-6xl">1</div>
    <div class="flex justify-center rounded-xl border-2 border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 p-6 text-6xl">2</div>
    <div class="flex justify-center rounded-xl border-2 border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 p-6 text-6xl">3</div>
    <div class="flex justify-center rounded-xl border-2 border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 p-6 text-6xl">4</div>
    <div class="flex justify-center rounded-xl border-2 border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 p-6 text-6xl">5</div>
    <div class="flex justify-center rounded-xl border-2 border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 p-6 text-6xl">6</div>
    <div class="flex justify-center rounded-xl border-2 border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 p-6 text-6xl">7</div>
    <div class="flex justify-center rounded-xl border-2 border-gray-300 bg-gray-100 p-6 text-6xl">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I want the columns to be adjusted dynamically based on screen size. Tailwind should recognize the device in which it is rendering and then adjust the columns dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

From [this thread](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/5541) in a Tailwinds GH Discussion, maybe something like:

```
grid grid-cols-[repeat(auto-fill,minmax(200px,2fr))]
```